# Which Qiskit Aer ideal quantum circuit simulator to use when aer_simulator is no longer available?

Tags: programming, qiskit

Some Qiskit tutorials have aer_simulator in the code and I have noticed that this simulator is no longer available.

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit import Aer
Aer.backends()
```

Which of the existing simulators should I use to replace aer_simulator?

The example tutorial is [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/simulators/1_aer_provider.ipynb).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `aer_simulator` was introduced in version 0.25.0 of Qiskit.

If it is not listed by `Aer.backends()` you should try upgrading Qiskit to the latest version.

You can use `pip install qiskit --upgrade` to install the latest version.